# Mui add a tooltip on TextField label is displaying two tooltip boxes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I'm trying to add a tooltip to a label prop of the TextField. And I need to make this work on touch screen, so I handle the open and close event manually.

But the tooltip appears as two different boxes

[image].

It looks weirder when I use ipad screen.

[image]

Anyone have idea about this?
Here is the sample https://codesandbox.io/s/draft-mui-tooltip-in-label-k9py2m?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the component in `label` isn't considered as part of the vDOM tree and you end up with multiple `Tooltip` elements.  Here I moved the `Tooltip` outside but kept its child inside the `label`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/draft-mui-tooltip-in-label-forked-hc9vvv?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You answered earlier than me and I appreciate your effort. It works, but there is an elegant and simpler way to do this. It's to use `FormControl`, `Tooltip` and `OutlinedInput` components. This way, you can put the label element in a `Tooltip` component and pass it to `FormControl`. You also need to pass the same label value to `OutlinedInput` to keep the layout.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you when I tried to add a tooltip to the label of an outlined `TextField`. It turns out that the `label` prop is not really the `label` component that you see on the screen. It's just used for some internal calculations, and the actual label component is `InputLabel`, which you can't customize in a `TextField`.

So what I did was to create my own `TextField` using `FormControl`, `Tooltip` and `OutlinedInput` components. This way, I could put the `label` element inside a `Tooltip` component and pass it to `FormControl`. I also had to pass the same label value to `OutlinedInput` to keep the layout consistent.

For example:

```
<FormControl>
  <Tooltip>
    <label htmlFor="component-outlined">Name</label>
  </Tooltip>
  <OutlinedInput
    id="component-outlined"
    defaultValue="Hello World!"
    label="Name"
  />
</FormControl>
```

This worked for me and I was able to add a `tooltip` to the `label` without any issues. You can check out the full example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/draft-mui-tooltip-in-label-forked-kvm9zc?file=/src/App.tsx)

This is basically how Material UI's `TextField` works behind the scenes, so you're not missing out on anything by doing this. If you want to learn more about how `TextField` is composed of different components, you can read this section of the docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#components

Comment: Thank you. That's a good and easy to understand anwser!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you could understand my answer. : ) - @NguyễnKhánhNguyên